# Changing background-color of a button using 1 javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button

I want to change the background-color of my button.
This is my code so far:

```
<script>
function setColor(btn) {
    var property = document.getElementById(btn);
    if (property.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(127, 255, 0)") {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 0, 0)"  
    }
    else if(property.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(255, 0, 0)")
    {
        property.style.backgroundColor = ""
    }
    else {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(127, 255, 0)"
    }
}
</script>

<input type="button" id="button" value = "button" onclick="setColor('button')";/>
```

This works with one button. If I have multiple buttons it only change the first button color. How can I change the color of every button with this JavaScript?

Comment: Change it all at the same time or each one to change on its click?

Comment: try this onclick="setColor('buttonId')"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="button" id="button" value = "button" onclick="setColor(this);"/>
```

js:

```
function setColor(btn) {
    if (btn.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(127, 255, 0)") {
        btn.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 0, 0)"  
    }
    else if(btn.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(255, 0, 0)")
    {
        btn.style.backgroundColor = ""
    }
    else {
        btn.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(127, 255, 0)"
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that all your buttons have the same `id` but id is meant to be unique so when you click on a button and you search by `id` you get the first one of all the buttons. So use unique ids

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```js
function setColor(btn) {
    var property = document.getElementById(btn);
    if (property.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(127, 255, 0)") {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 0, 0)"  
    }
    else if(property.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(255, 0, 0)")
    {
        property.style.backgroundColor = ""
    }
    else {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(127, 255, 0)"
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button" value = "button" onclick="setColor(this.id);"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is space issue in your script, I removed spaces in rgb colors in script and it is working fine

```
 <script>
   function setColor(btn) {
    var property = document.getElementById(btn);
    if (property.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(127,255,0)") {
       property.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,0,0)"  
     }
      else if(property.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(255,0,0)")
     {
         property.style.backgroundColor = ""
     }
     else {
         property.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(127,255,0)"
     }
  }
 </script>
```